# Android resource not found on some devices

Tags: android, android-activity, android-compatibility

Have an issue when running an app built with android studio (2.0 p4) on a Note 5. To clarify this works perfectly on emulator and other devices. *The app in the example is just the default "empty" app, having the exact same error as the app we are building*

Following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Throws following exception (on Note 5):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.note5test/com.test.note5test.MainActivity}:
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020016
```

R file:

```
public static final int abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha=0x7f020016;
```

If I just change to extend Activity (instead of AppCompatActivity) it works though, but I need to use the action bar so that is not an option.

Spent too much time on this now... Any clues?

Comment: "but I need to use the action bar so that is not an option" -- the action bar has been around in Android since Android 3.0. Assuming that your `minSdkVersion` is higher than 10, you can use the native action bar if you want. The `appcompat-v7` backport is for supporting older than Android 3.0 or for using a Material Design aesthetic on all versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was because I had an old version of the build tools, the version I used didn't handle resources correctly, so just updating to a new version made it all work.

Answer (score -1):

your case might be just wrong import of support libs, but also there is a chance that Note 5 OS have modified support lib built-in. With cutted some stuff, like methods (NoSuchMethod exception) or resources. It is worth to investigate if probably most current OS from Samsung (with Touch Wiz) does not reproducing similar problem with `AcitonBar` inflating on 4.2.2 on one of Mini... (duplicated packages of libs, instaled app using system ones, modified) Maybe try to change support lib version (22.2.+? or even older) in graddle, clean, build, try. There is also not-so-old `ActionbarActivity` (currently deprecated)

@CommonsWare In my opinion even if Okku supports only 4.0+ he also should use `AppCompatActivity`, it has more improvements, especially in layout inflating with widget customization and respects unified styling. Don't forget that current OS version is 6.0, there is more improvements than `ActionBar` introduced/changed :) (`Toolbar`!)

Comment: Thanks, i have tried 22.1.1 and 23.1.1 and clean/reboot device and computer.